# I always get the final print, even writing the class that I want. How do I fix this?

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to create a RPG just for fun. But, while creating the classes, I noticed that I couldn't choose my class. Everytime I choose a class, I always get the final print. How do I fix this?

```
while (True):
    print("Select your class\n")
    print("\nKnight\nArcher\nTank\nRogue\n\n")

    classe = input("")

    if((classe.strip()).lower() == "Knight"):
        forca = 10
        defe = 4
        hp = 8
        agi = 2
        inte = 2
        break

    elif((classe.lower()) == "Archer"):
        forca = 6
        defe = 6
        hp = 6
        inte = 8
        agi = 7
        break

    elif((classe.strip()).lower() == "Tank"):
        forca = 5
        defe = 8
        hp = 10
        inte = 3
        break

    elif((class.strip()).lower() == "Rogue"):
        strenght += 6
        def = 5
        hp = 5
        inte = 6
        agi = 10
        break
    else:
        print("You need to choose one.")
```

Comment: You use `.lower()` on the string and then compare to a word with a capital first letter. Try `classe.strip().lower() == "knight"`. You also need to check your parenthesis.

Comment: Tysm! I've been trying to figure out what was wrong and never thought about the capital letters. I'm feeling dumb rn lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.lower()` then comparing it to words with capital letters (`Tank`). So it will never match. Try this:

```
while (True):
    print("Select your class\n")
    print("\nKnight\nArcher\nTank\nRogue\n\n")

    classe = input("")

    if((classe.strip()).lower() == "knight"):
        forca = 10
        defe = 4
        hp = 8
        agi = 2
        inte = 2
        break

    elif((classe.lower()) == "archer"):
        forca = 6
        defe = 6
        hp = 6
        inte = 8
        agi = 7
        break

    elif((classe.strip()).lower() == "tank"):
        forca = 5
        defe = 8
        hp = 10
        inte = 3
        break

    # class is a keyword, use classe
    elif((classe.strip()).lower() == "rogue"):
        # Does this need to be an equals?
        strenght = 6
        # Def is a keyword, use defe
        defe = 5
        hp = 5
        inte = 6
        agi = 10
        break
    else:
        print("You need to choose one.")
```